# How can I add a catchError to an Angular http call using pipe and map?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

Trying to build in some simple functionality so that I can tell when an API call returns an error code of 401 (so that I can route back to the login page due to expired token.

I am trying to accomplish this by catching the error in the call and then logging the user out.

Currently my API service works perfectly but I cannot find a way to implement catchError correctly.

**Working Call**

```js
  getViT(x): Observable<CursorResult[]> {
    const url = hosturl +'vit';
        const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': ls
        }),
        withCredentials: true,
        params: {
        }
      };
    return this._http.get(url, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return <CursorResult[]> res;
      })
    );
  }
```

**Attempt to add catchError**

```js
  getViT(x): Observable<CursorResult[]> {
    const url = hosturl +'vit';
        const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': ls
        }),
        withCredentials: true,
        params: {
        }
      };
    return this._http.get(url, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(res => {
        return <CursorResult[]> res;
       }),
      catchError((err, caught) => {
        console.log('err ' + err)
        return err;
      })
   )
  }
```

Visual studio is telling me the following:

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CursorResult[]>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'CursorResult[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2322
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I was able to get the following code to work, but any time there was an error it would hit the API over and over again until I killed the docker container. Is this due to map?

```js
getViT(x): Observable<CursorResult[]> {
  const url = hosturl +'vit';
      const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': ls
      }),
      withCredentials: true,
      params: {
      }
    };
    return this._http.get<CursorResult[]>(url, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          return <CursorResult[]> res;
        }),
        catchError((err, caught) => {
          console.log('API Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
          return caught
        }),
      )     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Http interceptor solution:

```
@Injectable()
export class UnauthorizedInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    {
      return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              const _ = this.router.navigate(['login']);
            }
            return throwError(error);
          })
        );
    }
  }
```

and then define it as a provider in your module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: UnauthorizedInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this -- where would this code go in the code base? In the service itself or is another aspect of Angular altogether? Unfamiliar with interceptor.

Comment: I suggest to create a separate directory for interceptors. One thing that you need to do is to set this interceptor in your module provider section (I've updated my answer). It should work for all http requests. For more info you can check this article [https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)